# How to define a query om a n-m table

Tags: sql

I have some troubles defining a query.
I have a Product and a Category table. A product can belong to multiple categories and vice versa so there is also a Product-Category table.

Now I want to select all products that belong to a certain category. But if the user does not provide a category I want all products. I try to create a query using a join but this results in the product being selected multiple times if it belongs to multiple categories (in the case no specific category is queried).

What kind of query do I have to create?

Thanks

Comment: Use two different queries for this. There's no point joining onto the junction table at all if you aren't going to filter by it.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Products p
INNER JOIN ProductCategory pc ON p.id = pc.product_id
WHERE pc.category_id = 42
```

substituting the correct table and column names and the appropriate category id, of course. This will result in only one of each product, because you only get products from one category, as you mentioned. Notice you don't need the Category table in your query.

Edit:

As @Martin said somewhere else, if no category is specified, change the business logic to just get all the products from the database (i.e., `SELECT * FROM Products`).

Comment: From the question you would presume this is what the OP was already trying but I guess who knows? They may have done an inadvertent Cartesian join.

Comment: @Martin Yeah, I kind of assumed they would have gotten the Category table in there somehow, or used the wrong join, or something. @user559889 Ah, I see your edit now. I agree with @Martin that you should just do exactly what you said yourself: get all products for a certain category, or, if no category is specified, get all products.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.*
FROM   p
,      pc
WHERE  p.id = pc.productid
AND    pc.categoryid = <targetcategory>
```

something like this?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear. The issue is that sometimes no category is provided so then I want to return all products. But then I get duplicate products when products belong to multiple categories.